# Jenkins plugin get list of builders in multy builders plugin - return hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet cannot be cast to hudson.model.Project

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins

I writing Jenkins plugin which contain 2 Builders(builderA & builderB)
builderA has several input fields and will added to Jenkins job before builderB
builderB has no inputs

I'm using the following code to extract information from builderA during the builderB.perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener)

```
//loop on all the builders in this project and find  BuilderA
//from there we taking the CI/Release
String component;
String version;
Project buildProject = (Project) build.getProject();
List<Builder> blist = buildProject.getBuilders();
for (Builder b : blist) {
    if (b instanceof BuilderA) {
        listener.getLogger().println("BuilderA was found!!);
        BuilderA ba = (BuilderA) b;
        component = ba.getComponent();
        version = ba.getVersion();
        break;
    }
}
```

This work great if I create *Freestyle project*.

If I create *Maven project* the line: *Project buildProject = (Project) build.getProject();* throws" **java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet cannot be cast to hudson.model.Project**

Question:How can I get the list of Builders in *Maven project*.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. I change my code to support 2 different Jenkins job types:

```
List<Builder> blist = new ArrayList<Builder>();
if (build.getProject() instanceof hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet) {
  listener.getLogger().println("Build type: hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet");
  MavenModuleSet mms = (MavenModuleSet) build.getProject();
  DescribableList<Builder, Descriptor<Builder>> dl = mms.getPrebuilders();
  Collection<Builder> c = dl.toMap().values();
  blist.addAll(c);
}
else if (build.getProject() instanceof hudson.model.Project) {
  listener.getLogger().println("Build type: hudson.model.Project");
  Project<?, ?> buildProject = (Project<?, ?>) build.getProject();
  blist = buildProject.getBuilders();
}
```

also in pom.xml added reference to:

```
groupId=org.jenkins-ci.main
artifactId=maven-plugin
version=2.0
```